# How to find the first smaller value compared to the current row in subsequent rows?

Tags: r, rows, closest

Suppose this is the data:

```
data<-data.frame(number=c(4,5,3,1,0), 
             datetime=c(as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:25"),
                        as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:27"),
                        as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:32"),
                        as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:33"),
                        as.POSIXct("2015/06/12 12:10:35")))

  number   datetime
1      4 2015/06/12 12:10:25
2      5 2015/06/12 12:10:27
3      3 2015/06/12 12:10:32
4      1 2015/06/12 12:10:33
5      0 2015/06/12 12:10:35
```

I want to calculate the time between a row to the next smaller value. Desired output:

```
   number  next smaller   time between
1      4              3             7
2      5              3             5
3      3              1             1
4      1              0             2
5      0             NA          NA
```

Example: 3 is the first number in subsequent rows which is smaller than 4.

Any suggestion? package?

Comment: sort on number and use rowDiffs?

Comment: There are 100,000 lines, the result would be clearly wrong.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood the question.

Comment: Going by time and looking at number, wouldn't the next smaller of 4 be 5 with a time difference of 2?  Some more explanation would be good

Comment: I read it as the next smaller value in the "number" column. However the next smaller of 5 should be 4?

Comment: When the number is 4, where is the number after this row which is less than 4?

Comment: is the order of rows specified by their position rather than by respective values in the number column? This is the only way next smaller of 5 can be 3...and this is a bad bad bad way to organize ordered data.

Comment: The data is ordered by time. These are market data, I want to calculate when the price drops below the current price for the first time.

Comment: Then shouldn't nextsmaller be 3, 4, 1, 0, NA?

Comment: 4 has happened before 5, how could it be the next? They are ordered by time. For each row, we need to look at the following rows only not the whole data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not pretty and probably not super efficient, but it seems to get the job done.  Here we go ...

```
newcols <- with(data, {
    lapply(seq_along(number), function(i) {
        x <- number[-(1:i)][-i][1]
        c(x, abs(datetime[i] - datetime[number == x])[1])
    })
})

setNames(
    cbind(data[1], do.call(rbind, newcols)), 
    c(names(data)[1], "nextsmallest", "timediff")
)
#   number nextsmallest timediff
# 1      4            3        7
# 2      5            3        5
# 3      3            1        1
# 4      1            0        2
# 5      0           NA       NA
```

Comment: Richard, how the third line of your code works? Does it sort from the last to current? What does [-I] do? Searching everywhere ...

Comment: @Soheil - have you checked the result? I have a feeling this may be incorrect as it stands.  I need to figure out that specific line.

Comment: No yet,  anyway it is a great starting point, I'll try to find the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I'd suggest starting by ordering your dataframe in ascending order by 'number'. Next, add a new column using a lag function to retrieve the time value from the previous row. Finally, calculate the difference.

I could provide code later if you need it, but hopefully that will give you something to start with.

Comment: Sevyns, I am pretty sure that this would not work. You are solving different question.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking now; I'll take a look later and either edit or delete my answer.